# how to create a dictionary by adding string and list. python

Tags: python, dictionary

for example I have one string variable syn , and one list variable wordlist

```
syn="discipline"
wordlist=[u'discipline', u'horse Riding Discipline', u'academic Discipline']
```

I would like to get the dictionary looks like :

```
{ "discipline" : [u'discipline', u'horse Riding Discipline', u'academic Discipline'] }
```

how to do that?

Comment: [Documentation for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: The interesting thing is how are you going to generate the lists based on the `syn` I feel that was a harder problem for a beginner than creating a dictionary.

Comment: @Arc676 what, what, what - Documentation in this day and age, when everything should be `now` and not `later`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply access the variables you created:

```
syn = "discipline"
wordlist = [u'discipline', u'horse Riding Discipline', u'academic Discipline']
result = {syn:wordlist}
```

If you have several of these key/value pairs, add them with standard dictionary access syntax:

```
result = {}
data = [('dog', ['big dog', 'dogs']), ('apple', ['red apple', 'green apple'])]
for k,v in data:
    result[k] = v
```

Of course, if you have such a tidy object, just do `result = dict(data)`, but a loop as shown above can help you process your data and create a dictionary. A more specific algorithm will depend on exactly what sort of code you currently have.

Comment: thanks, the case is that the mydict is generating in the for loop, if i would like to append the dic and return it how to do that. such as the final dic will be looked like this: {'dog':['big dog, 'dogs'], 'apple': ['red apple', ' green apple']}

Answer (score 2):

Just go right ahead and do it:

```
mydict = {syn: wordlist}
```

Comment: thanks, the case is that the mydict is generating in the for loop, if i would like to append the dic and return it how to do that. such as the final dic will be looked like this: {'dog':['big dog, 'dogs'], 'apple': ['red apple', ' green apple']}

Answer (score 1):

```
some_dictionary = {}
some_dictionary[syn] = wordlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use **setdefault** (built-in type)

> This method returns the key value available in the dictionary and if
>   given key is not available then it will return provided default value.

like this

```
myDict =  dict()
myDict.setdefault(syn, wordlist)
print myDict
```

put *setdefault* inside your loop